# How to check integrity to HDD with UDF format

Tags: partition, hard-disk, fdisk, badblocks, udf

I'm having problem with a USB external drive, which seem to be  formatted with UDF and was being used for MAC and Windows (or at least that is what told).

When I attached the HDD to my Linux system the next are the `dmesg` entries:

```
[21784.312960] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
**[21784.406283] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1023**
[21784.406291] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1,Product=2,SerialNumber=3
[21784.406296] usb 2-1.2: Product: Elements 1023
**[21784.406299] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Western Digital**
[21784.406303] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: <The serial number>
[21784.406815] scsi8 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[21785.403470] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 1023    2005 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[21785.404686] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[21785.409491] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953519616 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[21785.410605] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[21785.411723] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[21785.411729] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[21785.413600] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[21785.414603] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[21785.414609] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
**[21785.449997]  sdb: sdb1 < >**
[21785.452466] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[21785.453503] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[21785.453515] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[21785.453524] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

With that information the HDD seem to be OK. However I'm unable to identify the type of partition (some commands from Windows console show is UDF but I can't confirm with Linux counterparts)

Trying to get more information, the `fdisk -l` outputs:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000202043392 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121600 cylinders, total 1953519616 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0bba88f0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               0  1953519615   976759808    5  Extended
fdisk: unable to read /dev/sdb1: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

As the partition doesn't mount, tools like `testdisk` and `fsck` can't work here (well `testdisk` and `photorec` just freeze trying to read the HDD). And due the size of the disk the `badblocks` command takes a lot of time (and is still running).

I can't find  many material about the UDF format (and I don't understand why a HDD use it when is ) and neither what to do when is unable to read any partition at all.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try `file -s /dev/sdb` which will look at the beginning of the disk and try to figure out the format.

Comment: I begin to think the original partition was FAT32 and maybe just maybe the MBR is what is lost.

Comment: You can try with `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model`; it may be able to tell what file systems there are; You may also want to install tools for UDF, see [**this link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706) and scroll down until you see the paragraph about UDF and the program package `udftools`. It should improve the chances to tell if there is really a UDF file system.

Answer (score 0):

I think Windows is mistaken in considering it an UDF disk. Windows is in my (fortunately limited) experience not the best judge of such things.

You could just try and mount the disk in read only mode:

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/udf
mount -o ro /dev/sdb /tmp/udf
```

trying /dev/sdb1 probably does not work. `fdisk` would also at least recognise a disc with `parted` partitioning information, but if the disc was partitioned on Windows/Mac there might be something it might not know about. You could use

```
gparted -l
```

and see if that brings you more.

I would however start with hanging this of a Windows and Mac and first make sure things work there before wasting your time on a possible empty/wiped disc on Linux.

Comment: Thanks @timo.  Trying to mount only read mode throw "mount: you must specify the filesystem type".  Gparted give the next error "Invalid partition table - recursive partition on /dev/sdb". Mac and Windows machine aren't able to mount the disc, however my first tries to fix it were with Windows own tools (chkdsk, partdsk, etc.) but were getting a error about "only read mode" and the info about the UDF filesystem.  By the way, I already tried to mount as exfat or Fat32 (Whcih are common to Windows/Mac) withouth success and badblocks didn't detect errors on the disk.